# MVC Get method not hit after javascript ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have these two controller methods that works:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditWork(string work)
{
    // do the bla bla
    return Json(new {Success = true});
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditWork(WorkObjet work)
{
    // Do the bla bla!

    var listWork = TempData.Peek("myWorks") as List<WorkObjet>;

    // Edit the value of the correct work object.

    return Json(new {Success = true});
}
```

And they get called via Javascript like this:

```
function EditWork(event, anc) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var param = anc.attributes["data-id"].nodeValue;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: @Url.Action("EditWork", "Work"),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { work: param }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.Success === true) {
            // Update the fields
        } else {
            console.log("Error:" + param);
        }
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
}

function SaveEdit(){
    var myWork = GetMyWork() // calls the field via jQuery

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: @Url.Action("EditWork", "Work"),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ work: myWork })
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.Success === true) {
            // reload the page?
            windows.location.reload();
        } else {
            console.log("Error:" + param);
        }
    }).fail(function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
}
```

And they work really well. So let's do the following:

1. Click on the button to edit a work
2. The Controller Get method EditWork is hit via breakpoint;
3. Edit the work, then save
4. The Controller Post method EditWork is hit via breakpoint and the work is updated in a list;
5. The page gets refreshed
6. Click on the button to edit again
7. The GET method is **not hit via breakpoint**, The **old work** gets shown at screen. Very odd.
8. Edit the work, then save
9. The POST method is hit with the values...

How is step seven even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens. But I know I was having a similar problem recently where my controller action wasn't hitting a breakpoint and I removed dataType from the AJAX call. For some reason, this worked for me. I'm not sure if we share the same problem though.

Comment: What shows up in the network tab of the console?

Comment: `GET` calls can be cached by the browser.  If using Chrome, e.g., go into dev tools, click the network tab, and check `Disable cache`.  Refresh the browser for it to take effect.

Comment: Network tab shows a request that processed almost instantaneously, and I did try to disable the cache with no avail.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms I have tried to remove those attributes from the request and it does not change a thing.

Comment: Oh, for information purpose, I'm using Internet Explorer (and I'm bound to use only IE)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: Back to the info in the network tab, what did the request look like?  Was it what you expected?  What was the response?  Was it what you expected?

Comment: @hsim I'm sorry to read that...

Comment: @nurdyguy Yep, and yep. Thanks for the support everyone. ;)

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Also, poor man's cache-buster, add `'?' + new Date().getTime()` to the end of the request url.

Comment: @Taki I do not see your point. I'm not caching anything in the controller if that's what you suggest.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez In fact even if I add that, or remove it, the string work value is not passed anymore. Makes sense because I need a string, not a JSON object in my Get method.

Comment: @hsim Did you try by removing: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` ? I mean: `$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: @Url.Action("EditWork", "Work"),
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    work: param
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  if (data.Success === true) {
    // Update the fields
  } else {
    console.log("Error:" + param);
  }
}).fail(function(xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});`

Comment: Did you try adding cache: false to your GET request?

Comment: @MartinD. That's what I wanna hear about. I'll check on that.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Yep.

Comment: @MartinD. please post your comment as an answer, it solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your GET request:

```
cache: false
```

By default jQuery allows browser to cache the result of GET Ajax requests. Look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.